# Fabric UI Navbar components- How to swtich to horizontal layout?

Tags: spfx, office-ui-fabric

How can i switch this component [Nav Fabric UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#Implementation) to change the layout to horizontal instead of vertical.
Are there any other Fabric UI components i can use a a menu horizontally?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using the [CommandBar](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/commandbar). I have created a Menu component and I set the items property from the `WebPart.ts` file (`MenuWebPart.ts`).

Below is the code for `MenuWebPart.ts`.

```
export default class MenuWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IMenuWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMenuProps> = React.createElement(
      Menu,
      {
        items: [
          { name: 'Documents', url: 'http://example.com', key: 'key3', isExpanded: true },
          { name: 'Pages', url: 'http://msn.com', key: 'key4' },
          { name: 'Notebook', url: 'http://msn.com', key: 'key5' },
          { name: 'Long Name Test for ellipse', url: 'http://msn.com', key: 'key6' }
        ]
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
```

And below is my code for the `Menu.tsx` file.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IMenuProps } from './IMenuProps';
import { CommandBar } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/CommandBar';

export default class Menu extends React.Component<IMenuProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: IMenuProps) {
    super(props);
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IMenuProps> {
    const { items } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <CommandBar items={items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

With this configuration, if you run your application, you will be able to see the menu in horizontal as follows.

[image]

Comment: What about sub items under each item